# SVN revision message in CruiseControl.Net

Tags: svn, build, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Using CruiseControl.Net build server.  I have a cc.net project that uses a SVN trigger.  During the build I would like to have the svn revision message for the changes that triggered the build.

Is it possible to get this ? I know CruiseControl is aware of this message as it is in the publish emails.

I am currently only using CruiseControl.Net. If this can be achieved using something like Nant, that would be fine.

Purpose : The result of the build is a single dll that the build commits to svn.  This message will be used as the commit message

Comment: So you want to get the SVN revision / message of the currently executing build?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/01/add-subversion-revision-to.html

Comment: @SameerSingh yes, the revision that triggered the build

Comment: @Web You could write a simple task that writes that info to a file as part of the build process and have CCNet execute it. Then another task that reads the file and uses it to commit to SVN with the message post-build

Answer (score 1):

Just enable the [Modification History Project Plugin](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_History_Project_Plugin) in the WebDashboard and you'll see the messages of each change since the last integration.

**Update**

Then maybe the [Modification Reader Task](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Reader_Task) could help.

It also depends on your client. Do you have the [Modification History Publisher](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/ModificationHistory_Publisher) enabled? It write the modifications into the build log. With this information any client could read them like the Webdashboard does with the Modification History Project Plugin.

Comment: I am not using the webdashboard.  The message needs to be available at build time.  I edited my post with the reason for this.